# Constrained optimization problem of 4 variables!

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I am stuck with this problem. I thought of trying to first solve the problem with weak inequalities for all the constraints using Kuhn Tucker conditions, and checking for solutions at which the constraints for $s$ and $t$ are slack. It is getting very messy, though. Am I on the right track or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, forget about the strict inequalities for now -- if the maximum turns out to be on $s=0$ or $t=0$, there will simply be no solution.

You can simplify the objective function a bit by making the substitution
$$s = (1+x+y)^2 \bar{s}^2$$
$$t = (1+x+y)^2 \bar{t}^2.$$
This will lead to extremely unpleasant KKT conditions which Mathematica can solve exactly to yield
\begin{align*}
x = y &= \frac{1}{600}\left(-251 + \sqrt{2401 + 150000\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
s = t &= \frac{\left(49 + \sqrt{2401 + 150000\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}{4500000},
\end{align*}
with objective value $\approx 0.34$. Now to check the boundary cases:

1. $s\to \infty$ or $t\to \infty$: clearly the objective diverges to $-\infty$.
2. $x\to \infty$: diverges to $-\infty$ unless $s=0$, in which case the maximum is 25 at $t=2500, y=0$.
3. $y\to \infty$: clearly the same case as the previous one.
4. $x = 0$: besides the $t=0$ case already analyzed above, there is a new critical point (again, extremely unpleasant to write down) with objective value $\approx 0.33$.
5. $y=0$: same as above.

So, your problem has no maximum: the objective approaches a least upper bound of $25$ at $t=2500, y=0$, and $s\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please tell me what made you make those substitutions for $s$ and $t$? And did you then optimize wrt $\bar s$   and $\bar t$ instead of $s$ and $t$?

Comment: @bitter-sweet It eliminates both two inequality constraints and replaces some square roots with polynomial expressions. And yes, of course.

Comment: Thanks again. What is the problem with directly telling Mathematica to solve the optimization problem using NMaximize? Would be great if you could shed light on this. Also, I finally got enough reputation points to upvote your answer :)

Comment: @bitter-sweet NMinimize will find a *local* minimum. If that's all you need, it works great.

Comment: I need a global max. I assume you mean that NMaximize would churn out a local max only when a global max doesn't exist, as in this case. Anyway, at (x, y, s, t)≈(0, 352.551, 2499.96, 5.01411×10^-7), the objective func has a value ≈25.0004. Mathematica gave me this and I verified it. So 25 isn't an upper bound. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @bitter-sweet are you *sure* the extra .0004 isn't numerical error? Check again with higher precision.

Comment: hmmm ok. t is very close to 0 here, so it must be the same as the case that you have analyzed. It's the first time I'm learning what mathematica does and doesn't do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ok one more thing- if I include s=0 and t=0 in the domain, then the function does indeed have a global max of 25, right?

Comment: @bitter-sweet yes.